# Стоит ли комбинировать ключевые слова в мета-описаниях?

Tags: html, seo

Давайте сразу перейдём к примеру, чтобы понять, о чём я говорю.
Как будет лучше написать из приведённых ниже двух вариантов?

```
<!-- Вариант 1 -->
<meta name="keywords" content="купить автомобиль москва, купить автомобиль в москве">

<!-- Вариант 2 -->
<meta name="keywords" content="автомобиль, купить, москва">
```

Второй вариант не очень хорош тем, что сайт попадёт в поисковик и у тех, кто набирает просто "Москва" или просто "Автомобиль", хотя конечно далеко не первое место в результатах поиска. Но возможно, что поисковик автоматически комбинирует эти слова, превращая второй вариант в первый (не знаю, так ли это, потому и спрашиваю).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если посмотреть по популярным сайтам продажи авто (rst, avito, infocar e.t.c.), то они похоже также не знают ответа на этот вопрос. И они комбинируют оба запроса. То есть, Ваш keywords будет выглядеть с их точки зрения так

```
<meta name="keywords" content="купить автомобиль мocква, купить автомобиль в мocквe, автомобиль, купить, мocквa">
```

Но, насколько я знаю, поисковики хоть и смотрят в эти слова, но они ещё активно смотрят и в содержимое страницы. И вот оно наиболее важно. Потому что, если в ключевых словах написано продажа автомобиля, а на самом деле покупаются лайки (и  даже не собаки), то поисковики могут и понизить в выдаче.

Answer (score 0):

Где-то писалось, что meta keywords вообще игнорируется, поскольку спам-страницы ими злоупотребляют. Содержимое страницы важнее ключевых слов.

Comment: Я то же не раз об этом слышал. Но раз эксперты ещё не дали зелёный цвет на "снятие с вооружения" ключевых слов (как, например, эксперты Google официально отказались от PR) , значит их использование пока ещё требует к себе серьёзного отношения.